# Radio button misbeahaving in angular 4 (inside of ngFor)

Tags: angular

```
<li *ngFor="let x of addressdata;let i = index">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="radio" [value]="x.PreferedAddress" [(ngModel)]="x.PreferedAddress" (ngModelChange)="RadioCheck(i)" name="radiogroup" id="Prefered"/>
  </div>
</li>
```

from db i get 3 rows and binding correctly, for particular row only have PreferedAddress=1 remaining has value 0.
but in list  by default last row radio button is checked

Comment: what you exactly want? can you please share your angular code?

Comment: Radio button workes well with the name. name must be the same for one group of radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There many ways to bind radio button using *ngFor:

```
<li *ngFor="let x of addressdata;let i = index">
   <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="radio" [checked]="x.PreferedAddress==1" 
           (ngModelChange)="RadioCheck(i)" name="radiogroup" />
   </div>
</li>
```

This is way to do it based on your requirement

**Note:** If you are using `[(ngModel)]` then you don't need id and value attribute.

Comment: Thanks Sanoj , Its working fine . may i know what is the issue if i fill [(ngModel)]

Comment: You can check the documentation here (https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

Comment: model value not getting if i remove [(ngModel)] this. if i select another radio button .. how can i get that change

Comment: You can change it from this `RadioCheck(i)` function find index and update value to 1 if you select current radio button and rest of update value set to 0.

Comment: Remove (ngModelChange)="RadioCheck(i)" instead `(change)="RadioCheck(i)" like this.

Answer (score 1):

you use name property dynamic and check in your array variable assign for radio button must have type Boolean.improve code below..

**in  html** use name="radiogroup-{{i}}"

Answer (score 0):

You use primitive values (strings), so you need to use a custom trackby function.

```
customTB(index, item) {
  return `${index}-${item.PreferedAddress}`;
}
```

In your HTML

```
<li *ngFor="let x of addressdata;let i = index; trackBy: customTB">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="radio" [value]="x.PreferedAddress" [(ngModel)]="x.PreferedAddress" (ngModelChange)="RadioCheck(i)" name="radiogroup" id="Prefered"/>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

checked needs to get string, anyway, this is my solution:

```
getChekedState(x: any): string {
    if (x.PreferedAddress==1) {
        return 'checked';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

then in your html:

```
[checked]="getChekedState(x);"
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that you didn't set your id and code value here is your improve code

```
 <li *ngFor="let x of addressdata;let i = index">
        <div class="col-md-2">
             <input type="radio [value]="x.PreferedAddress [(ngModel)]="x.PreferedAddress" (ngModelChange)="RadioCheck(i)" name="radiogroup" id="Prefered-{{i}}"  />
         </div>
    </li>
```

maybe this code help you and if its not work then share your complete code with me so I can help you

Comment: why someone gives me -1? this code helps you to set an individual to radio button value and it's work for me?